# for(i=0;True;i++) in python?

Tags: python

Is there a more pythonic way, or at least a shorter and simpler way, to do this:

```
i = 1
while True:
    res = lookup(i) # returns a value or None
    if res is None:
        break
    else:
        i += 1
        yield res
```

Comment: that is the most "pythonic" way, but not the shortest or simplest (`count(1)`). Your code is actually pretty simple: you don't need the `else:` and indentation at the end

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could make use of [`itertools`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html):

```
from itertools import takewhile, count

# ...
def myfunc():
    return takewhile(lambda x: x is not None, (lookup(i) for i in count(1)))
```

If you don't like `takewhile` for whatever reason:

```
for i in count(1):
     res = lookup(i)
     if res is None: break
     yield res
```

Comment: @Boud: Right, otherwise we'd stop on falsy values as well (like `0` or the empty list)

Comment: shorter, but I'm not quite sure it's simpler

Comment: @foosion: If you know `takewhile`, this is pretty obvious at the first glance and has the advantage of being a composition of functional elements, rather than a collection of imperative statements. Using the appropriate library function for the job is "Pythonic"

Comment: @foosion: I added another version with a plain old for loop

Comment: @NiklasB. Everything is intuitive once you're very familiar with it :)  Count is what I was looking for

Comment: @NiklasB Great summary, I agree.

Comment: If the value of `lookup(i)` is never falsey, then the lambda can be change to `lambda x: x`.

Comment: @Steven: Yeah, but that's not part of the question, so I can't assume it's the case

Answer (score 3):

Without going into `itertools`...

```
i = 1
res = lookup(i)
while res is not None:
    i += 1
    yield res
    res = lookup(i)
```

Comment: This one duplicates the code `res = lookup(i)`. I think OP used `while True` to specifically eliminate that duplication.

Comment: It's shorter and simpler, even with the duplication

Comment: Well, I don't like the code duplication, either, but the loop is certainly simplified :P. Not that I have anything against `itertools`, though...

Comment: @foosion: You could remove the `else`, in which case your original code would be just as short.

Answer (score 3):

`itertools.count` can count indefinitely up:

```
for i in itertools.count(1):
    res = lookup(i)
    if res is None: break
    yield res
```

Comment: count is what I was looking for.  much better than i=1, while True and i+=1